# Is it possible to disable scroll for users while leaving it enabled for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, layout, scroll, safari, single-page-application

Is there any way to disable scrolling for a user, while leaving the ability to change, say, scrollTop and scrollLeft available to the application itself?

When we say 'scroll' we actually mean Scroll, because setting .style.margin, .style.transform or .style.left/top all trigger forced layout, which causes problems in a browser we need to support.

Alternatively, is anyone aware of what specific difference between Webkit (Safari) and Blink (Chrome) causes them to handle .style-invoked forced layouts so differently?

We have an app which for various reasons needs to render about 18,000 DOM nodes and then fluidly navigate a viewport so that the user is looking at a specific set of them at any given time.

This is easily accomplished in Chrome and Firefox by using a coordinate system and setting .style.left and .style.top on the viewport element, but of course accessing and changing those forces a layout.  Chrome and Firefox are able to see that we don't actually need this and don't do it.  Safari, though, actually goes through with the force layout each time, which imposes a navigation lag of nearly a full second on the user.

An alternative to accessing .style would be to use .scrollLeft and .scrollTop (we've already tried using transforms, alas), but this requires that the big blob of DOM-nodes be scrollable, which allows the user themselves to scroll around in the blob (with, say, the mouse-wheel or a fat-finger on their phone), which is not desirable.

In short, we want the app to be able to scroll to specific locations when the user tells it to in specific ways, but we don't want the user to be able to scroll on the element without interacting with those specific ways, because that produces a bad user experience.

We are aware that rendering less content would mask the problem, we're already looking into that, but doing so would lock out certain behaviors the client finds desirable.

/edit/ We've also now tried dynamically creating css classes for every position we might possibly need (yes, we recreate them on browser resize), and even using these classes to sidestep inline styles, we get layout threshing from Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently overflow-hidden is not an inheritable attribute, so our assumption that the child would have it if the parent did was erroneous.

Because no overflow attribute had been set on the scrollable child at all, scrolling failed when it was attempted.

When overflow-hidden was correctly applied to the element, we reclaimed the ability to scroll without allowing the user to scroll undesirably.

... and also felt a bit silly.